# Merge multiple files into one on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

A rather stupid question but how do I combine multiple files in a folder into one file without copying them to local machine?I do not care about the order.
I thought hadoop fs -getmerge would do the job but I have since found out that it copies the data into your local machine.

I would do it in my original spark application but adding coalesce is increasing my runtime by a large amount.
I am on Hadoop 2.4 if that matters.

Comment: What benefit would combining the files provide?

Comment: @cricket_007 HDFS doesn't handle small files well. Merging small files with proper block size definitely increases speed.

Comment: @waltersu I am aware of the small file problem. Question didn't specify sizes. And small files wouldn't be a problem to merge onto local disk.  I'm just saying, like the results of an operation results in one output per reducer, the entire directory can be read as a new input for a job. Those files need not be combined

Comment: @cricket_007. Yeah, if it's not small files, merging doesn't gain benefits.

Comment: @cricket_007 I need to merge the files so an upstream batch process can then use it. I do not own that process and I am required to return a single file.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I combine multiple files in a folder into one file without copying them to local machine?

You have to either copy the files to local node or one of the computation node.

HDFS is a file system. It doesn't care about your file format. If your file is raw text/binary, you can try the *concatenation* API which only manipulate metadata in NameNode without copying data. But if your file is parquet/gzip/lzo or else, these files can't not be simply concated, you have to download them from HDFS, merge them into one, and upload the merged one. Spark's *coalesce(1)* do the same thing except it's done in the executor node instead of your local node.

If you have many folders has files need to be merged, spark/MR is definitely the right choice. One reason is the parallelism. The other reason is, if your file is like gzip doesn't support *split*, one huge gzip file may slow down your job. With some math calculation, you can merge small files into relative large files. ( file size equals to or slightly smaller than blocksize). It very easy with *coalesce(n)* API.

---

I suggest you to merge small files. But as @cricket_007 mentioned in the comment, merging doesn't always gain benefit.